# INSERT in Stored Procedure called via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, ssms, temp-tables

I have an MSSQL Server 2008 (Express) set up.
In my database I have a set of tables and a stored procedure.

What I want to achieve is get any changes that have been made to an existing table, and return them at the end of the procedure. The stored procedure I have created works fine when I run it locally within MSSQL Management Studio.

However, when I call the procedure through a JDBC connection certain parts of the procedure seem to have not completed.

The summary of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
1) Put a snapshot of the data contained in CurrentTableA into #CurrentShotA (temporary table)

2) Compare #CurrentShotA with PreviousTableA 

3) Insert differences into #TempTableB 
(this equates to new rows or altered rows in #CurrentShotA)

4) Empty PreviousTableA

5) Insert contents of #CurrentShotA into PreviousTableA

6) Select * from #TempTableB (return all new rows and changes)
```

Step 6 returns the data correctly the first time it is called via JDBC.
When the procedure is called the second and subsequent times it is clear that step 5 has not completed as expected. PreviousTableA is always empty when it should contain a snapshot of the old data.

Question is why does the procedure work properly when called with in MSSQL Management studio but not when I call it via JDBC?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getUpdatedSchedules] 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Check of the temporary table exists, delete if it does
        IF OBJECT_ID('#TempTableB','U')IS NOT NULL
        begin
            drop table #TempTableB
        end

        -- Force the creation of the temporary tables quickly
        select * into #TempTableB from dbo.CurrentTableA where 1=0
        select * into #CurrentShotA from dbo.CurrentTableA where 1=0

        -- Get the differences between schedules and put into #TempTableB
        insert #CurrentShotA select * from dbo.CurrentTableA
        insert #TempTableB select * from #CurrentShotA 
        except select * from dbo.PreviousTableA

        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.PreviousTableA       
        insert dbo.PreviousTableA select * from #CurrentShotA
        select * from #TempTableB
    END
GO
```

I'm new enough to stored procedures and MSSQL configuration so I have considered that it might be a permissions issue. I login to MSSQL Studio using SQL authentication that is not linked to a windows account and the procedure runs as normal so I don't think it's permissions.

I hope my explanation and question is clear enough. I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't help the issue, but you may want to do `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.PreviousTableA` rather than `delete from dbo.PreviousTableA where scheduleID > -1`, assuming that there are no records where scheduleID <= -1.

Comment: Ah, excellent, that was on my todo list.  Thank you.

Comment: I have resorted to creating an actual table in the database that has a copy of the data, I name it based on a timestamp within the stored procedure.
When I call my procedure from JDBC, data from the table is returned yet when I go and look in SSMS the table doesn't exist. I create it via SELECT * INTO [tableName_timestamp] from currentTableA

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check if #TempTableB exists since it will be dropped automatically once the procedure finishes executing, just as the other temp tables are dropped automatically; perhaps you expect these tables to have data on subsequent calls to the proc and that's why you think it doesn't work when you call it from Java?

When you execute these SQL statements from SSMS they may have data in them since it's all the same database session, but that's not the case when called using JDBC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only table that I expect to have data is the previoustableA one which should be populated from the temp table within the procedure. I understand that the temp tables don't persist. The drop was there to make testing with ssms easier. Not sure what's going on :(